# server ran out of memory uploading a file

Tags: node.js

i have a node js project, that i run on a free render account.
I use it to upload files to a google drive account and then create and return a public link:

```
app.post("/upload-file-to-google-drive2", multer.single("file"), async (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.file) {
    res.status(200).send({error:"No file uploaded."});
    return;
  }
  const auth = authenticateGoogle();
    let body = req.body
    const response = await uploadToGoogleDrive(req.file, body.id, auth);
    res.status(200).json({ response });
});

const uploadToGoogleDrive = async (file, fid, auth) => {
    var idx = file.originalname.lastIndexOf('.')
    let ext = idx == -1 ? '' : file.originalname.substring(idx)
  const fileMetadata = {
    name: `file${fid}${ext}`,
    parents: [googleFolderId],
  };
  const media = {
    mimeType: file.mimetype,
    body: streamifier.createReadStream(file.buffer),
  };
  const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });
  const response = await drive.files.create({
    requestBody: fileMetadata,
    media: media,
    fields: "id",
  });
    let id = response.data.id
    drive.permissions.create({
      fileId: id,
      requestBody: {
        role: 'reader',
        type: 'anyone',
      }
    });
    const webViewLink = await drive.files.get({
    fileId: id,
    fields: 'webViewLink'
    })
  return webViewLink.data.webViewLink;
};
```

It works fine, but now i tried to upload a big video (399MB) and i got an error. The Server events show `Ran out of memory (used over 512MB) while running your code.`
Is there any way around this?

Comment: In general, you're probably better off sending it directly to an object store like Amazon S3 so the server doesn't have to do anything. In Node: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node (Heroku docs, but largely usable elsewhere).

Comment: If I correctly understand, you store the file in memory on your server and then you upload it to Google Drive. You could use a stream instead.

Comment: @jabaa i am pretty new to node js. Can you show me how to do that?

Comment: Remove multer. It stores the file. You can access the file stream though `req` and pipeline it with: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streampipelinesource-transforms-destination-options I won't write the whole code for you. Maybe you can even replace `streamifier.createReadStream(file.buffer)` with `req.stream`.

Comment: I think `req` is already the stream. You could try to pass it as value for `body`.